Derivation of two-body Coulomb interaction in momentum space
$\newcommand{\vec}{\mathbf}$
In Condensed Matter Field Theory by Altland and Simons, they claim the two-body Coulomb interaction for the nearly-free electron model for a $d$-dimensional cube with side lengths $L$ takes the form
$$
\hat{V}_{ee} = \frac{1}{2L^d}\sum_{\vec{k}, \vec{k}', \vec{q}} V_{ee}(\vec{q}) a^\dagger_{\vec{k} - \vec{q}} a^\dagger_{\vec{k}' + \vec{q}} a_{\vec{k}'} a_{\vec{k}}
$$
where $V_{ee}(\vec{q}) = \frac{e^2}{q^2}$ represents the Fourier transform of the potential $V_{ee}(\vec{r}) = \frac{e^2}{r}$ in units where $4 \pi \epsilon = 1$.
I have several questions:

Shouldn't there be an additional $4\pi$ factor on $V_{ee}(\vec{q})$, i.e., $V_{ee}(\vec{q}) = \frac{4\pi e^2}{q^2}$?
Doesn't this result only hold for $d = 3$ since the $d$-dimensional Fourier transform of the $3$-dimensional Coulomb potential $V_{ee}(\vec{r}) = \frac{e^2}{r}$ for $d= 1, 2, 3$ depends on $d$?
When I try to calculate this in $d = 3$ from the position space representation of the operator, I do not know how to recover the expression in the textbook. I will show my attempt at performing this calculation below:

We start from
$$
\hat{V}_{ee} = \frac{1}{2}\int d^d r \, d^d r' \, V_{ee}(\vec{r} - \vec{r}') \, a^\dagger(\vec{r})a^\dagger(\vec{r}')a(\vec{r}')a(\vec{r}),
$$
where the integrals are from $-L/2$ to $L/2$ in each coordinate. Since $V$ is diagonal in position space, we can write
$$
\hat{V}_{ee} = \frac{1}{2}\int d^d r_1 \, d^d r'_1 \, d^d r_2 \, d^d r'_2 \, \langle r_1, r_1' | V_{ee} | r_2, r_2' \rangle \, a^\dagger(\vec{r}_1) a^\dagger(\vec{r}'_1) a(\vec{r}'_2) a(\vec{r}_2).
$$
Inserting two momentum resolution of identities, we then get
$$
\hat{V}_{ee} = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{\vec q, \vec q', \vec k, \vec k'} \langle q, q' | V_{ee} | k, k' \rangle \, a^\dagger(\vec{q}) a^\dagger(\vec{q'}) a(\vec{k'}) a(\vec{k}),
$$
where the momenta are quantized in units of $2 \pi / L$. When I evaluate $\langle q, q' | V_{ee} | k, k' \rangle$ by inserting a position resolution of identity $\int d^d \vec{r} \, d^d \vec{r'} |r, r' \rangle\langle r, r'|$, where again the integral is from $-L/2$ to $L/2$ in each spatial dimension, I then get
$$
\langle q, q' | V_{ee} | k, k' \rangle = \frac{e^2 \delta_{\vec k + \vec k', \vec q + \vec q'}}{L^{2d}} \int_{-L/2}^{L/2} d^d u\frac{e^{i u (\vec k' + \vec q')}}{|\vec u|},
$$
and after this I do not know how to proceed.
I know if we take the limit $L \to \infty$, the above expression becomes
$$
L^{2d} \langle q, q' | V_{ee} | k, k' \rangle = \frac{4\pi e^2 (2\pi)^d\delta(\vec k + \vec k' - \vec q - \vec q')}{(\vec k' - \vec q')^2}
$$
by the usual calculation of the Fourier transform of the Coulomb potential in three dimensions. Then, we can approximate the momentum sums as integrals and we have
$$
\hat{V}_{ee} = \left(\frac{2\pi}{L}\right)^{4d}\sum_{\vec q, \vec q', \vec k, \vec k'} \left(\frac{L}{2\pi}\right)^{4d} \frac{L^{2d}}{L^{2d}}\langle q, q' | V_{ee} | k, k' \rangle \, a^\dagger(\vec{q}) a^\dagger(\vec{q'}) a(\vec{k}') a(\vec{k})
$$
becomes
$$
\hat{V}_{ee} = \frac{e^2 L^{2d}}{(2\pi)^{3d - 1}}\int dq dq' dk dk' \frac{\delta(\vec k + \vec k' - \vec q - \vec q')}{(\vec k' - \vec q')^2} \, a^\dagger(\vec{q}) a^\dagger(\vec{q'}) a(\vec{k}') a(\vec{k})
$$
or equivalently, after integrating and performing a change of variables,
$$
\hat{V}_{ee} = \frac{e^2 L^{2d}}{(2\pi)^{3d - 1}}\int dq dk dk' \frac{1}{q^2} \, a^\dagger(\vec k - \vec{q}) a^\dagger(\vec k' + \vec{q}) a(\vec{k}') a(\vec{k}).
$$
which seems somewhat compatible with the answer in the textbook.
Edit: Fixed a typo in the last line.
Edit: This doesn't really directly answer the question, but if we pass back to the discrete limit after passing to the continuum limit, then we have
\begin{align*}
\hat{V}_{ee} &= \frac{e^2 L^{2d}}{(2\pi)^{3d - 1}}
\int dq dk dk' \frac{1}{q^2} \, a^\dagger(\vec k - \vec{q}) a^\dagger(\vec k' + \vec{q}) a(\vec{k}') a(\vec{k})\\
&= \sum_{\vec k, \vec k', \vec q} \frac{e^2 L^{2d}}{(2\pi)^{3d - 1}} \left(\frac{2\pi}{L}\right)^{3d} \frac{1}{q^2} \, a^\dagger(\vec k - \vec{q}) a^\dagger(\vec k' + \vec{q})a(\vec{k}') a(\vec{k})\\
&= \sum_{\vec k, \vec k', \vec q} \frac{2 \pi e^2}{L^d} \frac{1}{q^2} a^\dagger(\vec k - \vec{q}) a^\dagger(\vec k' + \vec{q})a(\vec{k}') a(\vec{k}),
\end{align*}
which is the same as the expression in the textbook after multiplying by the $4\pi$ factor mentioned at the top of the post.

(1) The Americans love their imperial units, and never learnt to do SI units properly, so that even when they do science, they would use Gaußian units. It is a headache trying to pin down all the $4\pi\varepsilon_0$ issues, and you would be far better served finding another source that sticks to SI units. (2) The title of the book is Condensed Matter... are you expecting a $d\neq3$ in our universe? (3) This particular derivation is quite common, though usually done without all the quantum field creation and annihilation operators. Find them.


No, but I was expecting maybe $d = 1$ or $d = 2$ for one-dimensional or two-dimensional materials, respectively. 3) Sorry, could you give me some key words that I could use to find a source on Google or potentially a reference? I tried looking on stackexchange for a derivation but I didn't find one. Thanks.


(2) This is the correct time and place to discuss that there is a "number of space(time) dimensions" v.s. "1D, 2D and 3D materials". The $d$ that appears can refer to either, and usually even in 1D or 2D materials, the relevant Coulomb interaction still goes as $d=3$. Authors tend to be extremely sloppy about this very important distinction, and you have to beware. (3) Try https://young.physics.ucsc.edu/116C/sing_ft.pdf

(2) Yes, I tried to distinguish between the two in the post by saying the $d$-dimensional Fourier transform of the $3$-dimensional Coulomb potential (instead of, say, the $d$-dimensional Fourier transform of the $d$-dimensional Coulomb potential). (3) It seems like all the derivations in that document are about the Fourier transform from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ when I'm asking about evaluating the Fourier transform of the Coulomb potential for finite $L$.

Oh, finite $L$, that is almost always called Fourier series and not transform. It is used often in matter modelling, which has its own SE site. IIRC there is nothing particularly special about it, except that you throw away the $k=0$ value as being unphysical. In numerical packages like FFTW, the $k=0$ term is the first term, and thus easy to zero if you need to.

What most books essentially do is that they employ periodic boundary conditions, periodize the potential in a suitable manner, and replace the Fourier coefficients in the Fourier series by the Fourier transform. This is valid in the thermodynamic limit. For finite $L$, the computation of the integral is very hard, I believe. For a spherical volume it is doable, though. See e.g. this.


This is not possible to answer without knowing all of your source's relevant conventions, including the Fourier transform. One way you can check the book is look for a place where they use this interaction to compute a known observable, and see if there's a corresponding place they are off by $4\pi$ in that derivation.

You are correct that the position space potential depends on $d$. However, the momentum space interaction will generally be $\sim q^{-2}$, at least at large $L$ (when we can use Fourier integration instead of a sum). This follows from dimensional analysis.
$$
\int d^d x \frac{e^{i q x}}{x^{d-2}} \sim \frac{1}{q^2}
$$
The left hand side has dimensions of $\left({\rm length}\right)^2$. There is only one dimensional parameter in the integral -- the wavenumber $q$, which has dimensions of  $\left({\rm length}\right)^{-1}$. So the scaling with $q$ of the right hand side is fixed. You do have to be a little careful in $d=2$, because the potential is a log instead of a power law.

The dimensional analysis argument above is enough to get the general form, $\sim e^2/q^2$, up to order 1 factors. I think to do an exact calculation you should be able to simplify the integral you obtained further. I would probably just directly compute the Fourier transform of $V(r)$ as a starting point. But looking at your expression, up to powers of $L$ and ignoring factors of $\pi$, I think you essentially do have the correct answer. The correct form, converting sums to integrals, should be
$$
V_{ee} \propto \int d^d q \int d^d k \int d^d k' \frac{e^2}{q^2} a^\dagger(k-q) a^\dagger(k'+q)a^(k) a(k')
$$
That matches what you have, except you have $a^\dagger(k+q)$, but given how closely everything else works I'm assuming that's a typo or easy-to-fix algebra error.


The $L$ dependence should cancel out in the limit $L\rightarrow \infty$. Essentially, $1/L \rightarrow dx$ in the limit $L\rightarrow \infty$. (Depending on your conventions, there are probably also powers of $2\pi$ involved in this correspondence).
To go from the Fourier transform to the Fourier series case, you obviously need to deal with that pesky integral. In the continuum limit you can evaluate the integral by moving to spherical polar coordinates. But that doesn't directly help you in the finite box case. I suspect you could do some kind of trick exploiting periodicity to do something where you argue that the integral with the correct bounds is proportional to the integral with $L\rightarrow \infty$ where you know the answer, but admittedly this step I don't know off the top of my head. (I'll update if I think of or find something).

Another idea for doing the integral in the lattice case is to rewrite the integral using theta functions
$$
\int_{R^3} d^3 u \frac{e^{i u x}}{u^2} \prod_{i=1}^3 \theta(u_i-L/2) \theta(u_i+L/2)
$$
then introduce the integral representation of $\theta$
$$
\theta(u) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0} \int_{-\infty}^\infty dz \frac{e^{i u z}}{z-i\epsilon}
$$
then change the order of integration to do the $u$ integrals first and leave the $z$ integrals until the end.
